# ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, machine-learning

I'am trying to generate my own training data for recognition problem. I have two folder `s0` and `s1` and the folder containing is `data`.
`images`, `lables` are the two list in which the `labels` contains the names of the folder.

```
|—- data
|    |—- s0
|    |    |—- 1.pgm
|    |    |—- 2.pgm
|    |    |—- 3.pgm
|    |    |—- 4.pgm
|    |    |—- ...
|    |—- s1
|    |    |—- 1.pgm
|    |    |—- 2.pgm
|    |    |—- 3.pgm
|    |    |—- 4.pgm
|    |    |—- ...
```

Below is the code, it's showing me an error on line `classifier.fit(images, lables)`

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mint.py", line 34, in <module>
 classifier.fit(images, lables)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py",  line 150, in fit
  X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=np.float64, order='C')
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-   packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 396, in check_array
  % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
```

ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
 here

```
import os,sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
fn_dir ='/home/aquib/Desktop/Natural/data'

# Create a list of images and a list of corresponding names
(images, lables, names, id) = ([], [], {}, 0)
for (subdirs, dirs, files) in os.walk(fn_dir):
    for subdir in dirs:
      names[id] = subdir
      mypath = os.path.join(fn_dir, subdir)
      for item in os.listdir(mypath):
        if '.png' in item:  
        label=id
        image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(mypath, item),0)
        r_image = np.resize(image,(30,30))
        if image is not None:
            images.append(r_image)
            lables.append(int(label))
      id += 1  
#Create a Numpy array from the two lists above
(images, lables) = [np.array(lis) for lis in [images, lables]]
classifier = SVC(verbose=0, kernel='poly', degree=3)
classifier.fit(images, lables)
```

I really don't understand how to correct it in 2 dimension.
I am trying the below codes but the error is same:
   
    `images = np.array(images)
    im_sq = np.squeeze(images).shape
    images = images.reshape(images.shape[:2])`

Comment: `images.append(cv2.imread((path, 0))` I count 3 open parens and 2 close parens.

Comment: yes, I make it. but the new error is `TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, tuple found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is syntax error on `images.append(cv2.imread((path, 0))` last line in your code. The parenthesis are not closed properly. So it should be like this `images.append(cv2.imread((path, 0)))` . Also it is always a good thing to post the traceback for the error so that it will be easy for anyone to answer.

Comment: yes, thank you... but trace back was showing in the next line... that's why I every looking to same line.... and I did this, but I am getting other `TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, tuple found`